# How to does one make the transisition from advertising to information technology?

Tags: ads

I have a friend that has been in the advertising industry for 20 years or so, 10 of which he has been self-employed.  He is a 'creative director', which means that he develops concepts, sells them to clients, writes copy, produces media (print or video), etc.  Think Michael and Elliot's characters in the show 'Thirtysomething'.

Recently, he mentioned to me that he wants to get out of advertising and into IT.  I guess my stories of [sarcasm]super-sexy work[/sarcasm] and multi-month assignments (as opposed to his day- or week-long ones) have left him thinking of changing jobs.

Problem is, he has no programming background.

The most obviously entry point are areas that build on his existing skills.  I've mentioned CSS design and Flash animation.

Other than the skill-set limitations, I think he needs to understand his options and what it will cost him in time and money to pursue them.  I don't thing going back to school is an option, however.

Suggestions from those of you that have made a transition from other fields to IT are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where this belongs but I don't think it belongs on stack overflow.

Comment: agreed.  While I'll always welcome newcomers to the fold, this question is not programming related and very subjective.

Comment: Once you've been in advertising, there's no turning back. The evil has taken hold.

Comment: An advertising professional wants to quite his job and learn IT because it has multi-month assignments? Is he serious?

Comment: @Remus: lol, this is very funny.

Comment: @moayad Yes, I don't think he'll be enjoying programming much where it's common to work on the same project for years. Unless it's general IT in which case broken computers usually come and go by the week

Comment: Not really sure what is meant by "IT" in this context. Surely he does not want to be a programmer before even knowing anything about programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have the question of what part of IT does he really want as there are more than a few different parts:

1. Project Manager - Perhaps as a creative director he oversaw projects and can handle schedules and budgets, but this is a part of IT.
2. Quality Analyst - Testing can be a common entry point as while this does require attention to detail, there aren't a lot of technical skills like a developer would have.
3. Tech Support/help desk - Instead of trying out something, one has to handle given problems and give solutions to people.
4. Business Analyst - While this is a bit of a decoding job, his advertising background may be useful in knowing how some people would like a system to work.
5. System Administrator - If he wants the power trip of being given big responsibility and deal with possible bureaucracies.

Those are a few possibilities where he has to figure out which role he wants, what is he prepared to do to fit that role well and why he should get that entry level job in IT.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how his experience in advertising field will help him become a Project Manager or Business Analyst. Those jobs need years of experience in the field of IT itself.

Comment: The domain knowledge that he has from advertising may be useful in those roles.  In the BA case, he may have a better understanding of how would end-users use various systems for things like campaigns or programs to state a couple examples.  The PM one is more of not having to start from the very beginning possibly as handling non-technical projects may have parts that transfer to a technical PM.  There may be the question of how much diversity have you seen in various PMs and BAs could also be a factor.

Comment: I think he likes to be creative.  My bias says that those options, while still valuable, aren't in alignment with his goals.

Thoughts?

Comment: If it were easy I'd suggest have him shadow someone that is a programmer to get a better idea of what it really is and covers.  Alternatively, if there are local user groups that may be useful for him to talk to other members about their work to get a better idea of all the things programmers do, that may help as well.